# Rewrite URL in asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I redirect url based on register client in c# .net or asp.net 4.0. For example if client registers as "client1" and our website is www.mycompany.com for every page client proceeds should get www.client1.mycompany.com.

More detailed example:

For example another client created is Client2. The pages i have created in general is like

```
 "www.mycompany.com/product.aspx" 
 "www.mycompany.com/categories.aspx" should be shown as
 "www.client2.mycompany.com/product.aspx" and
 "www.client2.mycompany.com/categories.aspx"
```

respectively
I have searched on web and found for static pages or using Gloabal.asax during startup of application but haven't found any thing after user logged in.

Comment: The parameter is in the hostname - just to check, you have your DNS already configured to make it work and use the same Website/App set up in IIS?

Comment: So wish to redirect each request based on the user-being-looged info?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    //DLL: Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll    

    //web.config
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
        <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
      </configSections>
    </configuration>

    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>


    <rewriter>
        <rewrite url="~/(.+)/CompanyHomePage" to="~/Home.aspx"/>
    </rewriter>


    //C#:

     string strTitle = Session["company_name"].ToString();
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');
     strTitle = strTitle.ToLower();
     char[] chars = @"$%#@!*?;:~`+=()[]{}|\'<>,/^&"".".ToCharArray();
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("c#", "C-Sharp");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("vb.net", "VB-Net");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("asp.net", "Asp-Net");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace(".", "-");

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        string strChar = chars.GetValue(i).ToString();
        if (strTitle.Contains(strChar))
        {
           strTitle = strTitle.Replace(strChar, string.Empty);
        }
    }
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace(" ", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("-----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim();
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');

     Response.Redirect("~/" + strTitle + "/CompanyHomePage", false);//Redirect to ~/Home.aspx page


//reference: CompanyHomePage same in web.config  <rewrite url="~/(.+)/CompanyHomePage" to="~/Home.aspx"/> which company is log in to sight that company name show in url like this http://abcd//CompanyHomePage
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing so.
ub1k stated on one way.

I think the easiest way is using the global.aspx.cs
(If you don't have global.aspx then add it) and then

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentPath = Request.Path.ToLower(); //get the request
    var myContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (currentPath == "/addUser" || currentPath == "/newuser") //decide what to do with the request
        myContext.RewritePath("/login.ashx?path="+ currentPath);
     else  //default value
        myContext.RewritePath("/default.aspx");
}
```

Easy, clear and very powerful...

Comment: +1 ..seems like the easiest way to me, rather than add a module just for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to make redirects based on client login - which is an internal application thing (cannot be handled by IIS - like with the IIS Url Rewriter) then you should probably create a `HttpModule`.

So what you should do is:

- Create a module -> class that implements `IHttpModule`
- In this module implement your redirecting logic
- Plug it in, in web.config secion: `<configuration><system.web><httpModules>` like:

  `<add name="MyModule" type="MyModule.Module, MyModule" />`

All can be found at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996

Mind you kave to hook your logic to an event that is done `after` the authentication is done. 
I also believe that to read the user info you should have your module implement also `IRequiresSessionState`