# Does ASP.NET have an extension point through which all URL generation code is passed?

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a way to alter URLs generated by calls to on the many methods on [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [`Control.ResolveUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a way that is completely transparent for the developer.

The main scenario is adding a language 'tag' to URLs. The developer creates a link to an action or to an ASPX page as usual, but the URL generation is 'intercepted' to make the link 'language aware' so to speak. I would prefer not to see this cross-cutting concern 'leak' into the code. (When the user clicks the link, the language tag in the URL is interpreted, and the request is rewritten, so it 'just works'.)

Does ASP.NET have the required extension point to do this? In other words: what kind of class can I register (and where do I register it) that is called always when a URL is generated?

A cursory glance at the source code at [aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com) indicates that ASP.NET ultimately relies on the [`VirtualPathUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, but unlike the [`VirtualPathProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) (used to resolve incoming URLs to files on disk) it cannot be implemented (it's a static class).

Comment: You could also not change the URLs, but change how they are _interpreted_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Not my favorite way of handling urls but take a look at: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite .  This happens at the IIS level.  Otherwise the class you're looking for is the one you don't want to use for w/e reason and that's routing.  I recommend routing though over url rewrite, it's a lot more manageable, but if you want something quick for a one off use url rewrite.

Comment: Global.asax could help, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107213/rewrite-url-in-asp-c-sharp/15108446#15108446

Comment: Those are great examples for handling/interpreting incoming requests. My concern is more about generating consistent URLs for hyperlinks on the page.

Comment: @michielvoo, I'm sorry, I can still don't understand what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: @Ran How would you automatically add "/en" or "/de" to the front of all relative links on all pages, based on the thread's culture?

Comment: @michielvoo, now I think I understand. If you do not want to add a variable to each of your link. I would suggest garbing all the links controls in your page and change them auto -> foreach (Control c in page.Controls) if (c is HtmlAnchor || c is HyperLink) ... change the link

Answer (score 0):

Its nasty but you could register a http module which greps/string replaces your URLs in your responses with what you need.  This would involve using a series of regexes to get at the html emitted and swapping out with what you need, which would be even easier if you could have a placeholder in the URL to begin with.

Other than that writing your own bespoke methods and then doing find and replace with their counterparts wouldn't be too onerous.

Maybe even AOP might be useful if you could mark the method where you wanted to do your replacement and could get instance data into it (not sure this is a starter)

Or how about custom attributes, which could be enumerated on a page and have the instance of the page passed in for more fine grained control (similar to the way domain object validators might work) whereby controls housing the offending URLs could be accessed and rigged.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really looking for a way to 'just' use things like UrlHelper.Action() and have it return the URL with a language tag appended to it.